# How to shrink and move the view in android?

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to shrink and animate the Relative layout into right side like below **Image**, am using `translate` animation to move the layout to right side(translate animation working fine), but not able to shrink the view.Am not able to achieve like image.Can any one know help me to solve this issue.

[image]

Whenever click the button(Three line button) in relative layout.shrink the view and move it right side.

**Translate animation code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fillEnabled="true" >

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="90%" />

</set>
```

**Java Code**

```
bt1 =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (view_moved != 1) {
              Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.translate);
              anim_lay.startAnimation(animation);
              view_moved = 1;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Use [Scale Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html) to shrink the view

Comment: @arol_8021 When i shrink using scale animation the button inside the layout is not good to view.

Answer (score 0):

View animation does not resample the views drawable, only applies scale matrix to it so it might become blurry or have artifacts. Use object/value animator to animate layout's height/width instead so that it is redrawn on every change.

```
    ValueAnimator widthAnim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(viewGroup.getMeasuredWidth(), desiredWidth);
        anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = viewGroup.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.width = val;
                viewGroup.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
        });

    ValueAnimator heightAnim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(viewGroup.getMeasuredHeight(), desiredHeight);
        anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = viewGroup.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.height = val;
                viewGroup.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
        });
   AnimatorSet scaleAnimation = new AnimatorSet();
   scaleAnimation.playTogether(widthAnim, heighthAnim);
   scaleAnimation.setDuration(500).start();
```

where `viewGroup` is your RelativeLayout

Comment: what is 'anim' here again?